# Insert tab creating issues: Sed treats first tab as literal character and then as whitespace thereafter

Tags: sed

I am using sed to insert a line within a formatted apache conf document, and I would like to keep the formatting. To do this, I need to insert the line with tabs.

Here is my command:

```
 sed -i "/DocumentRoot\s\/data\/iga\/wwwroot/a \t\t\tServerName itWorked" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

And here is the output:

```
                DocumentRoot /data/iga/wwwroot
t               ServerName itworked
```

What I need is for sed to treat the first "\t" as a tab, rather than as a "t" such that the output is as follows:

```
                DocumentRoot /data/iga/wwwroot
                ServerName itWorked
```

Comment: Is it Mac OS/BSD sed? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42321/how-can-i-instruct-bsd-sed-to-interpret-escape-sequences-like-n-and-t

Comment: It is GNU sed on a Debian image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try instead:

```
sed -i "/DocumentRoot\s\/data\/iga\/wwwroot/a\\\t\t\tServerName itWorked" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

or

```
sed -i '/DocumentRoot\s\/data\/iga\/wwwroot/a\\t\t\tServerName itWorked' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
# enclosed with single quotes
```

The `a` command expects a backslash in front of the replacement text,
then you need to add extra backslashes.

Note that the `\t` kind of notation in the replacement is supported by
`GNU sed` only. A standard `sed` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{print} sub(/DocumentRoot\s\/data\/iga\/wwwroot.*/,"ServerName itworked")' file
                        DocumentRoot /data/iga/wwwroot
                        ServerName itworked
```

The above will use whatever spacing is present in the "DocumentRoot" line rather than requiring you to specific the spacing again in your command. To make the changes "inline" add `-i inline` and that'll work with GNU awk just like `-i` works with GNU sed - `awk -i inline '...' file`.